KEYCLOAK 24.0.4 - How to Internationalize display names of attributes
I define new attributes for my users, like phone number, country, town, etc.
I would like these attributes be edited using internationalized labels.
The standard distribution contains various languages english, french, … associating labels with strings in différent languages. We can then refer by ${my_label} in the page description and Keycloak transforms that by the correct translation.
My problem is adding some new labels like ${my_label} and define their corresponding translations in different languages.
Could anybody help?
Thanks a lot
I am running Keycloak with docker and I supposed that I needed to add some files like messages_en.properties in /opt/keycloak/themes/ directory, but i tried without any success.

I am not clear with your question. What you mean by internalized labels? Can you please edit you question with more information?
